# Finding The Elapsed Time From A Text File

Tags: vb.net

So, I am importing data from a text file, and sorting them based on certain information into different list boxes. An example of the data will be below; however I need to find the elapsed time of the entries. So i need to subtract the last entries time stamp from the first entries time stamp. I am unsure how to extract that specific data from the first and last line from the list box or text file, I also need to do this to two separate cells.

For example:
**This is the first production cell:**

Production Cell 1, 4/20/2018 2:09:18 PM, 340

Production Cell 1, 4/20/2018 3:13:48 PM, 211

**Second Cell:**

Production Cell 2, 4/20/2018 2:09:24 PM, 531

Production Cell 2, 4/20/2018 3:13:45 PM, 720

**Please Note That Both Cells Are Jumbled Up In The Same Text File, Not In Order**

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBvPG.png)

Current Sorting Based On Colour: 
Still Need:Elapsed Time, the weight and Go/NoGo is based on the values at the end and I have not attempted that yet.

```
 Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True ' Returns to original start directory

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        m_FileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        srFile = New StreamReader(m_FileName) ' Need new instance of the object, this is necessary

        While Not srFile.EndOfStream
            strLine = srFile.ReadLine

            If strLine.Contains("Production Cell 1") Then
                lstProductionCell1.Items.Add(strLine)

                If strLine.Contains("PM, 1") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 1") Then
                    white1 += 1
                    lblWhiteCell1.Text = CStr(white1)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 2") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 2") Then
                    black1 += 1
                    lblBlackCell1.Text = CStr(black1)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 3") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 3") Then
                    red1 += 1
                    lblRedCell1.Text = CStr(red1)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains(" PM, 4") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 4") Then
                    yellow1 += 1
                    lblYellowCell1.Text = CStr(yellow1)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 5") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 5") Then
                    green1 += 1
                    lblGreenCell1.Text = CStr(green1)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 6") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 6") Then
                    blue1 += 1
                    lblBlueCell1.Text = CStr(blue1)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 7") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 7") Then
                    brown1 += 1
                    lblBrownCell1.Text = CStr(brown1)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 8") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 8") Then
                    grey1 += 1
                    lblGreyCell1.Text = CStr(grey1)

                End If

            ElseIf strLine.Contains("Production Cell 2") Then
                lstProductionCell2.Items.Add(strLine)

                If strLine.Contains("PM, 1") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 1") Then
                    white2 += 1
                    lblWhiteCell2.Text = CStr(white2)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 2") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 2") Then
                    black2 += 1
                    lblBlackCell2.Text = CStr(black2)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 3") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 3") Then
                    red2 += 1
                    lblRedCell2.Text = CStr(red2)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains(" PM, 4") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 4") Then
                    yellow2 += 1
                    lblYellowCell2.Text = CStr(yellow2)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 5") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 5") Then
                    green2 += 1
                    lblGreenCell2.Text = CStr(green2)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 6") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 6") Then
                    blue2 += 1
                    lblBlueCell2.Text = CStr(blue2)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 7") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 7") Then
                    brown2 += 1
                    lblBrownCell2.Text = CStr(brown2)

                ElseIf strLine.Contains("PM, 8") Or strLine.Contains("AM, 8") Then
                    grey2 += 1
                    lblGreyCell2.Text = CStr(grey2)

                End If
            End If
        End While


    End If


    srFile.Close() ' Be sure to close the file
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to format the code to make it more readable. And you forgot to share the code in the question.

Comment: Hopefully that is a little more clear for you Chetan.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to get the difference between `4/20/2018 2:09:18 PM, 340` and `4/20/2018 3:13:48 PM, 211` for Cell1 and display it in `lblTimeCell1`. And the same for Cell2 and display it in `lblTimeCell2`

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The trick is that the text file contains hundreds of time stamps, so I am unsure if I should use the first and last entry of the list box for each cell, or somehow sort the text file as I am reading it based on the time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of the code is alien to me. I do not understand on what base you are trying to determine values for white, black, grey etc color values. So I am not attempting to correct it.

Anyways, based on the problem you described about identifying the difference between the dates of cells in from the text file, I tried to come up with following solution.

I have written a sample console application to replicate the use case.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim inputData = New List(Of String)()
        'I am using generic collection here for the input data instead of file.
        'You can use File.ReadAllLines method to read all the lines from file and store them in an array.
        ' Dim inputData = File.ReadAllLines(m_FileName)
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 1, 4/20/2018 2:09:18 PM, 340")
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 1, 4/20/2018 3:13:48 PM, 211")
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 2, 4/20/2018 2:09:24 PM, 531")
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 2, 4/20/2018 3:13:45 PM, 720")
        Dim cellDates = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of DateTime))()
        Dim prodCell1 As String = "Production Cell 1"
        Dim prodCell2 As String = "Production Cell 2"

        For Each item In inputData
            Dim lineItems = item.Split({","c})
            Dim datePart = lineItems(1).Trim() & lineItems(2)

            Dim dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(datePart, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)


            If Not cellDates.ContainsKey(lineItems(0)) Then
                cellDates.Add(lineItems(0), New List(Of DateTime)())
            End If

            cellDates(lineItems(0)).Add(dateValue)
        Next


        'Sorting dates of both the Cells.
        Dim prodCell1Dates = cellDates(prodCell1).OrderBy(Function(dt) dt)
        Dim prodCell2Dates = cellDates(prodCell2).OrderBy(Function(dt) dt)
        'You can add the dates values in the listboxes here as following.

        'lstProductCell1.DataSource = cellDates(prodCell1)
        'lstProductCell2.DataSource = cellDates(prodCell2)


        'Getting difference between the last and the first date.
        'This returns an instance of TimeSpan
        Dim prodCell1Duration = prodCell1Dates.Last() - prodCell1Dates.First()
        Dim prodCell2Duration = prodCell2Dates.Last() - prodCell2Dates.First()
        'Display difference in the form of total minutes in the Console.
        'You need to write code here to display values in the proper labels.
        Console.WriteLine(prodCell1Duration.TotalMinutes)
        Console.WriteLine(prodCell2Duration.TotalMinutes)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Useful links
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

This would help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I really liked sorting the lists by date and the using First and Last to get the TimeSpan.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting the data imported into a usable format then you can reference  everything more easily like 'CellData(2).Elapsed'

```
'Put Structure and 'global' arrays at module level
Structure EachCell
    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim FinishTime As Date
    Dim CodeNumber As Integer
    Dim Elapsed As TimeSpan
End Structure
'
Private DataInFile() As String
Dim CellData(999) As EachCell
'leaving (0) element unused
'
 Private Sub MyRoutine()

    Dim threeparts As String(), CellRefNo As Integer, Temp As Date

    If IO.File.Exists("MyFilePath") Then
        DataInFile = IO.File.ReadAllLines("MyFilePath")

        For Each dataline As String In DataInFile
            If dataline.StartsWith("Production") Then
                'split dataline on comma
                threeparts = dataline.Split(","c)
                'refno/array index is 3rd element of first part  
                CellRefNo = CInt(threeparts(0).Split()(2))

                If IsNothing(CellData(CellRefNo).StartTime) OrElse CellData(CellRefNo).StartTime = DateTime.MinValue Then
                    'if .starttime field previously unused 
                    CellData(CellRefNo).StartTime = CDate(threeparts(1))
                Else
                    CellData(CellRefNo).FinishTime = CDate(threeparts(1))
                End If

                If CellData(CellRefNo).StartTime > CellData(CellRefNo).FinishTime Then
                    'if start/finish in wrong order swap
                    Temp = CellData(CellRefNo).StartTime
                    CellData(CellRefNo).StartTime = CellData(CellRefNo).FinishTime
                    CellData(CellRefNo).FinishTime = Temp
                End If
                CellData(CellRefNo).Elapsed = CellData(CellRefNo).FinishTime - CellData(CellRefNo).StartTime

                CellData(CellRefNo).CodeNumber = CInt(threeparts(2))

            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a class and generic lists to keep track of data.

```
Class Form1
 Private Sub FillData()
        Dim inputData = New List(Of String)()
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 1, 4/20/2018 2:09:18 PM, 340")
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 1, 4/20/2018 3:13:48 PM, 211")
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 2, 4/20/2018 2:09:24 PM, 531")
        inputData.Add("Production Cell 2, 4/20/2018 3:13:45 PM, 720")
        Dim itgWhite1, itgBlack1, itgRed1, itgYellow1, itgGreen1, itgBlue1, itgBrown1, itgGrey1 As Integer
        Dim itgWhite2, itgBlack2, itgRed2, itgYellow2, itgGreen2, itgBlue2, itgBrown2, itgGrey2 As Integer
        Dim DataCell1 As New List(Of CellData)
        Dim DataCell2 As New List(Of CellData)
        For Each s As String In inputData
            Dim sArray() As String = s.Split(","c) 'the c provides the Char that .Split requires
            Dim cd As New CellData()
            cd.CellNumber = CInt(sArray(0).Remove(0, 16)) 'Remove the Production Cell part
            cd.CellDate = CDate(sArray(1).Trim)
            cd.CellDetail = CInt(sArray(2).Trim)
            If cd.CellNumber = 1 Then
                Select Case cd.CellDetail
                    Case > 799
                        itgGrey1 += 1
                    Case > 699
                        itgBrown1 += 1
                    Case > 599
                        itgBlue1 += 1
                    Case > 499
                        itgGreen1 += 1
                    Case > 399
                        itgYellow1 += 1
                    Case > 299
                        itgRed1 += 1
                    Case > 199
                        itgBlack1 += 1
                    Case Else
                        itgWhite1 += 1
                End Select
                DataCell1.Add(cd)
            Else
                Select Case cd.CellDetail
                    Case > 799
                        itgGrey2 += 1
                    Case > 699
                        itgBrown2 += 1
                    Case > 599
                        itgBlue2 += 1
                    Case > 499
                        itgGreen2 += 1
                    Case > 399
                        itgYellow2 += 1
                    Case > 299
                        itgRed2 += 1
                    Case > 199
                        itgBlack2 += 1
                    Case Else
                        itgWhite2 += 1
                End Select
                DataCell2.Add(cd)
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print($"
        White1 = {itgWhite1},
        Grey1 = {itgBlack1}, 
        Red1 = {itgRed1}, 
        Yellow1 = {itgYellow1}, 
        Green1 = {itgGreen1}, 
        Blue1 = {itgBlue1}, 
        Brown1 = {itgBrown1}, 
        Grey1 = {itgGrey1},
        White2 = {itgWhite2},
        Grey2 = {itgBlack2}, 
        Red2 = {itgRed2}, 
        Yellow2 = {itgYellow2}, 
        Green2 = {itgGreen2}, 
        Blue2 = {itgBlue2}, 
        Brown2 = {itgBrown2}, 
        Grey2 = {itgGrey2}")
        Dim Cell1Sorted As List(Of CellData) = DataCell1.OrderBy(Function(d) d.CellDate).ToList
        Dim Cell2Sorted As List(Of CellData) = DataCell2.OrderBy(Function(d) d.CellDate).ToList
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Cell1Sorted.ToArray)
        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(Cell2Sorted.ToArray)
        lblElapsed1.Text = (Cell1Sorted.Item(Cell1Sorted.Count - 1).CellDate - Cell1Sorted.Item(0).CellDate).TotalMinutes.ToString
        lblElapsed2.Text = (Cell1Sorted.Item(Cell2Sorted.Count - 1).CellDate - Cell2Sorted.Item(0).CellDate).TotalMinutes.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
Class CellData
    Property CellDate As DateTime
    Property CellNumber As Integer
    Property CellDetail As Integer
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"Procuction Cell {CellNumber}, {CellDate}, {CellDetail}"
    End Function
End Class
```